# ant build.xml to maven pom.xml utility

Tags: ant, maven-3

Is there any plugin available that will take my ant build.xml file and generate the pom.xml accordingly, in my current scenario i have a project built on ant standard the script will do auto generation of code building java doc compilation and other stuff, looking of plugin that will auto generate the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by an IDE that support both Ant and Maven, such as NetBeans. See [this post](http://k3andme.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/converting-ant-to-maven-in-netbeans/).